# SSMS Data Import Data Truncated Error mESSAGE

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

I am trying to import a state's voter registration csv file into SSMS. As expected it is a rather large file and every time I try to import it I get an error that The data conversion for column returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

This is occurring on multiple different columns and I tried changing the length in data source advanced settings, I've changed the DataType to Unicode string [DT_WSTR], and I've tried to change the mappings to nvarchar instead of varchar, and nothing seems to be working. Every time I try and run it I get the same error message. It is not one particular column that is causing the issues as I removed everything except one column and I still got the error.

I noticed that everything in this file is surrounded by double quotes "" I'm not sure if this could be influencing the error. If so, I'm unsure how to change it as excel and notebook refuses to open the file because it is too large.
[Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npBCi.png)

Comment: Changing from varchar to nvarchar wont change truncation, you would need to change the lengths of the varchar in your table.  You can first create staging tables with all VARCHAR(8000) or VARCHAR(MAX)  (or NVARCHAR if you have those data types that need it), then have a 2nd step that transfers it from your stage tables to your final tables.  Then you can run len checks on your stage if you are having issues to find what rows are causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

[DT_WSTR] has max legth 4000 . Try using ntext as both destination and source data type.